# Using ELMAH in currently running website

Tags: asp.net, elmah, production

I have a asp.net website developed in asp.net 2.0 on production which is using enterprise library for keeping the log/error and saving them into the text file. Can I use ELMAH without comipling the website and read log/error via ELMAH interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ELMAH can be very well used without recompile, however note that if your existing logging frameworks are handling errors, then elmah may not be able to get the error since other frameworks would have taken some actions and used up the stack trace of it.